# why a warning of "uninitialized value"?

Tags: perl

The following script is for exercise 4.6.4 in learning Perl. A "reverse list" is asked to be printed out without using `reverse`.

While the output was what the question asks for, I got a warning between the input and output, which says "`Use of unitialized value in print at line 18, <> line 4`".
I thought I've claimed the array in `line 10`. Why do I still get the warnings?

```
1      #!/usr/bin/perl
2      #exercise4_6_4
3      use warnings;
4      use strict;
5
6      print "Type in your list: \n";
7      my $input =<>;
8      chomp $input;
9      my $i=0;
10     my @array;
11     while ($input ne "") {
12        $array[$i] = $input;
13        $input =<>;
14        chomp $input;
15        $i++;
16        };
17     while ($i !=0) {
18        print $array[$i],"\n";
19        $i--;
20        };
21     print "$array[$i]";
```

Running the script shows the following:

```
Type in your list:
child
books
flight

Use of uninitialized value in print at exercise4_6_4.pl line 18, <> line 4.

flight
books
child
```

Comment: Also, for future reference... it might be a good idea to post code without the line numbers here on SO. :)

Comment: "Uninitialized value" does not mean an undeclared identifier, it means `undef`. It's not complaining about `@array` — arrays can never be "uninitialized" — but rather about `$array[$i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your last `$i++` on line 15 increments $i, loop ends, then line 18 tries to get `$array[$i]`, but you haven't stored anything in $array[$i].

You could add a `$i-- if $i > 0` between line 16 and line 17 to solve the problem.

For what it's worth, you can use push and pop and not have to worry about incrementing a counter

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Type in your list: \n";
my @input;
push @input,$_ while defined($_ = <>) && $_ ne "\n";
print pop @input while @input;
```

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot the last $i is one plus of the number of elements in the array! Sorry for the newbie error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to replace line 18 with something like this line:

`print $array[$i-1], "\n";`

Arrays have their limits. :)